# How to create a custom conditional activation function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, activation-function

I want to create custom activation function in TF2. The math is like this:

```
def sqrt_activation(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return tf.math.sqrt(x)
    else:
        return -tf.math.sqrt(-x)
```

The problem is that I can't compare `x` with 0 since `x` is a tensor. How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip the comparison by doing,

```
def sqrt_activation(x):
    return tf.math.sign(x)*tf.math.sqrt(tf.abs(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to use tf backend functions and convert your code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
@tf.function
def sqrt_activation(x):
    zeros = tf.zeros_like(x)
    pos = tf.where(x >= 0, tf.math.sqrt(x), zeros)
    neg = tf.where(x < 0, -tf.math.sqrt(-x), zeros)
    return pos + neg
```

note that this function check all tensor to meet on those conditions ergo returning the `pos + neg` line